# Robotgo cannot listen to more than one event

Tags: go, mingw, keyevent

I'm using [robotgo](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo) to listen to keyboard events. I would like to add my own functions for every key pressed but I am unable to get it to trigger for more than 1 key.

So the main function looks like this:

```
func main() {
    go addKeyListen("l")
    go addKeyListen("k")
}
```

The wrapper function:

```
func addKeyListen(key string) {
    for {
        if ok := robotgo.AddEvent(key); ok {
            fmt.Println("Pressed "+key)
        }
    }
}
```

After pressing `L` all I am getting is `Pressed l` and multiple times but I can solve that with a flag. Pressing `K` doesn't print anything.

Tried the following:

```
for {
    if okA := robotgo.AddEvent("k"); okA {
        fmt.Println("Pressed k")
    }
    if okB := robotgo.AddEvent("l"); okB {
        fmt.Println("Pressed l")
    }
}
```

First pressing K then L, then repeating this over and over seems to trigger the events but not if I change the key press order. So if I first start with L then K, nothing happens.

PD: Testing this from windows 10 with MinGW64 version x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0

Also tried different versions of MinGW from 4 onwards and same results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this, based on robotgo and lib used by it, tested on mac 10.14:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
    gohook "github.com/robotn/gohook"
)

func main() {
    eventHook := robotgo.Start()
    var e gohook.Event
    var key string

    for e = range eventHook {
        if e.Kind == gohook.KeyDown {
            key = string(e.Keychar)
            switch key {
            case "k":
                fmt.Println("pressed k")
            case "l":
                fmt.Println("pressed l")
            default:
                fmt.Printf("pressed %s \n", key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

:)